# CSRF Token Name on Django Documentation is not Matching the Actual Name of the Variable in AJAX Header

Tags: ajax, django, csrf

I was struggling to send and recieve CSRF token, and I found, in the end, that Django was not able to get the token value because its name was different from the recommended one in its documentation. Why?

(I am doing AJAX on a HTTPS address and requests are cross-site.)
[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/) recommends that I add token to AJAX header in following way:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Here, the name is X-CSRFToken, which somehow becomes HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN.
On the other hand, Django is looking up the cookie under CSRF_COOKIE.

Line 278 in csrf.py of CsrfViewMiddleware:

```
csrf_token = request.META.get('CSRF_COOKIE')
if csrf_token is None:
# No CSRF cookie. For POST requests, we insist on a CSRF cookie,
# and in this way we can avoid all CSRF attacks, including login
# CSRF.
   return self._reject(request, REASON_NO_CSRF_COOKIE)
```

I cannot change the variable name because I get this error:

```
Request header field CSRF_COOKIE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

So, I ended up changing the variable name in the source code from CSRF_COOKIE to HTTP_X_CSRFTOKEN. Are there any way to make this work?

(I do not do @csrf_exempt, so please do not recommend.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not from Django, if you read closely here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#how-it-works you will understand how it works and what kind of logic they follow.

The problem is that you are not allowing the headers:

```
Request header field CSRF_COOKIE is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

If you search for this ACAH you will find that you must edit your server config file to allow this kind of posts.

The other case is that you may not be sending properly the header and that's why it's looking for the cookie. In that case you can try adding this to your header:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken': $('meta[name="token"]').attr('content') });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. Do you have a link to the page explaining ACAH? Could not find. I am not using REST framework if that matters.